# Icons not showing properly in Divi Child Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, icons, wordpress-theming, child-theming

I'm working on a website (using Divi) and the icons don't show up correctly when I activate the child theme.

I've attached a picture to show the problem I am having:

[image]

This only happens when I activate the child theme, when I go back to the Divi theme, everything goes back to normal.

Additional info:

- I used a Divi child theme generator for the child themes.
- I used CSS and Elegant Themes Icon codes for the Icons.

Here is an example of the CSS I use for the icons:

```
.menu-donate:before {
    font-family: 'ETmodules';
    content: "\e089";
      color: #2a2f36;
        margin-right: 6px;
        margin-top: -2px;
    float: left;
}
```

How can I make the icons compatible with the Divi child theme?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Turning on the option for Dynamic Modules in the Performance Settings fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, after activating the child theme, the CSS was changed and the "\" was removed from the "\e089".

I added the "\" back in and it's working normally.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Divi>Theme Options>Builder>Advanced>Static CSS File Generation...and hit the CLEAR button ;)

Comment: Recently did a [WordPress site move on Dreamhost](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049679412), this issue appeared and this answer resolved it.

Comment: This is the answer! You don't need to go messing around with the code on Divi.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue with icons not showing up in my Divi child theme.  The solution I found that worked for me is this:
Place the following in your .htaccess file:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Webfont access
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your developer console for scripts/css that are not loading properly.